# Curious about how opencv_cudaoptflow.lib, where to find it or make?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am about to try YOLO as dll in **Win10, x64, opencv 3.4.0, CUDA 10, MSVS 2015** as suggested [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll).
All the steps are done but when I build I have an error

[image: error]

The curious part for me is I couldn't find that ***opencv_cudaoptflow340.lib***  anywhere, not in the CUDA folders, not in the opencv340 (where my opencv resides), not even in the whole PC. So, naturally I tried to find it on the web, no luck. Only possible solution seemed to be [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/337#issuecomment-360735820) with CMake building. Obviously I followed it, however, CMake didn't give an ***opencv_cudaoptflow340.lib*** option at all.

---

How should I approach to find/make/create this .lib file?
I would like to see your experiences on this.
I think this would help others too.
Cheers!

Comment: have you found any solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad I somehow could compile Opencv with CUDA as suggested [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/337#issuecomment-360735820), it took me some trials and fails though